# unable to understand write policy in Cache memory

Tags: caching, architecture, cpu-architecture

I am studying write policies in cache memory ( for first time ). I am able to understand the 'write-through' but i am not able to understand 'write back' and the problems associated with it . Please can anyone explain me the 'write-back' concept clearly .

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)#Writing_policies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When any block of data is brought from disk to cache, it means that the cache is holding a duplicate copy of the data on the disk. So, when there is a write operation on a block of data in the cache, then the data on that block has changed in the cache, and it should change in the disk storage as well.

In write-through cache, when there is a write on a block in the cache, then that write is implemented in the disk storage as soon as the data in the cache has changed. While this is a simpler approach, it does have a lot of overhead, because for every such write-through operation, there is a context-switch and a virtual to real memory address translation taking place, in addition to the time taken to write the block to disk.

However, in write-back cache policy, the writes occurring on cache blocks are not immediately reflected onto the disk storage. Only when that cache block is displaced from the cache, is the block data written back to the disk. So, that means there is a possibility that when you compare a block of data in the cache and the same block of data in the disk, they might not be the same.

Write-back caches are more complex, but they save a lot of performance overhead by only writing to disk storage when required (i.e. when the block is displaced from cache).